# How to make a Photoshop (.psd) file have hyperlinks when saved as a .PDF file?

Tags: url, pdf, hyperlink, photoshop

I created a template for a document i want to use, in photoshop.

I want to share this document as a PDF file.
I want some of the text i made in photoshop to work as hyperlinks and direct ppl to websites.

How do i save a photoshop file as a PDF and get hyperlinks to work in the PDF file?

I have tried using the slice tool. It works to assign a url and target.
But when saved as a PDF the links do not work.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that indesign allows for saving pdf documents in either print or web format. the latter allows for hyperlinks to be available. if photoshop does not offer this you can always add them in acrobat (not reader) and then resave the .pdf.